# Replacing column with column from another dataframe

Tags: pandas

I am a beginner in Python. I have two dataframes, named GB and New_df, each with 651 rows. Essentially I would like to replace the "MP" column in GB with the "MP" column in New_df.

I have tried both of the following

```
gb["MP"] = new_df["MP"]

gb["MP"] = [x for x in new_df["MP"]]
```

But then the values are out of alignment with the other columns in the datafraame.

Here is the full code:

```
import pandas as pd

gb = pd.read_csv("https://www.electoralcalculus.co.uk/electdata_1992ob.txt", sep=";")
gb = gb.sort_values(by="Name", ascending=True)
gb = gb.reset_index(drop=True)

new_df = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_MPs_elected_in_the_1992_United_Kingdom_general_election',
                      match='Constituency')
                      
new_df = new_df[0]
new_df.columns = ["Name", "MP", "Party"]
new_df = new_df[~new_df["MP"].str.contains("\[edit\]")]
new_df = new_df[~new_df["MP"].str.contains("MP")]
new_df = new_df.sort_values(by="Name", ascending=True)
new_df = new_df.reset_index(drop=True)

gb["MP"] = new_df["MP"]
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of each DataFrame including the index, and the matching expected output.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, your indices are not aligned. Consider this example:

```
#Preparing sample data
string = """A B C D
1 a a 1
1 a a 2
1 a a 3
2 a a 1
2 a a -1
3 a a -1
3 a a -2
3 a a -3"""


import numpy as np
data = [x.split() for x in string.split('\n')]
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(data[1:]), columns = data[0])
df['D'] = df['D'].astype(int)

#making new_df
new_df = df.copy()

#shuffling index of new df
s = df.index.to_list()
np.random.shuffle(s)
new_df.index = s

#Assigning back
df['new'] = new_df['A']
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C   D   new
0   1   a   a   1   2
1   1   a   a   2   1
2   1   a   a   3   3
3   2   a   a   1   2
4   2   a   a   -1  3
5   3   a   a   -1  3
6   3   a   a   -2  1
7   3   a   a   -3  1
```

Solution is to first sort your new df index:

```
new_df = new_df.sort_index()
```

then try assignment.